# Stored Procedure with mySQL to determine a volunteers language/methodology insert incorrectly

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble deriving a a stored procedure to allocate specific languages to a volunteer.

My requirements:

70% chance that English is spoken, and a 50% chance each for French and Hindi. Default is English if none of those are specified. Anyone who speaks French would prefer to read French. Otherwise, people prefer to read one of the languages that they can speak.

We built our tables in the main script:

```
create table not_volunteer ( -- (volunteer is a view)
member_num int not null auto_increment,
firstname varchar(50) not null,
lastname varchar(50) not null,
dateofbirth date not null,
primary key (member_num)
)

create table volunteer2languageREAD(
member_num int,
is_639_1 varchar(50),
foreign key (is_639_1) references languagee(is_639_1)
foreign key (member_num) references not_volunteer(member_num)
);

create table volunteer2languageSPEAK(
member_num int,
is_639_1 varchar(50) default 'en',
foreign key (is_639_1) references languagee(is_639_1),
foreign key (member_num) references not_volunteer(member_num)
);
```

We have language procedures:

```
procedure 'french_generation'(in nfolks int)
BEGIN
declare exit handler for 1452
set @t = (nfolks - @x) * 0.5;
set @r = 0;
while @r < @t do
insert into volunteer2languageSPEAK(member_num, is 639_1)
values(@r+1, 'fr');
insert into volunteer2languageREAD(member_num, is 639_1)
values(@r+1, 'fr');
set @r = @r + 1;
end while;
END
```

And the same for English:

```
procedure 'english_generation'(in nfolks int)
BEGIN
declare exit handler for 1452
set @x = (nfolks - @x) * 0.7;
set @y = 0;
while @y < @x do
insert into volunteer2languageSPEAK(member_num, is 639_1)
values(@y+1, 'en');
insert into volunteer2languageREAD(member_num, is 639_1)
values(@y+1, 'en' or 'fr' or 'hi');
set @y = @y + 1;
end while;
END
```

And Hindi:

```
procedure 'hindi_generation'(in nfolks int)
BEGIN
declare exit handler for 1452
set @t = (nfolks - @x) * 0.5;
set @r = 0;
while @r < @t do
insert into volunteer2languageSPEAK(member_num, is 639_1)
values(@r+1, 'hi');
insert into volunteer2languageREAD(member_num, is 639_1)
values(@r+1, 'hi' or 'fr' or 'en');
set @r = @r + 1;
end while;
END
```

We are stuck, our goal is to be able to do query analysis at the end with specific select statements, and we need to make sure languages are put in the right way.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some sample result table? Also, could you elaborate what your problem with your procedures is? "Being stuck" is not really clear. At first glance, your procedures should not insert any rows (or at least not the right amount), but  it could also be any number of problem, and knowing what the problem is (e.g. an incorrect result table compared to the expected result table, an error message, an infinite loop, ...) is a tremendous help to help you solve your problem.

Comment: It does not insert any rows, sorry for the unclarity. Our goal is to declare a volunteer language (70% English, 50% Hindi and 50% French).

Comment: A sample result would be more conrete than "declare a volunteer language (70% English, 50% Hindi and 50% French)" . E.g. it's unclear if "@x" in the hindi-procedure is supposed to be a global session variable with an effect on the other procedures, or a mistake. You could probably simplify your question by limiting it to your 3 `create table` (good that you added them!) and only 'hindi_generation' (as e.g. replacing 0.5 with 0.7 makes no new problem) with the result table for that procedure (and, if necessary, an explanation), and all error messages and/or incorrect results you got.

Answer (score 0):

Your Procedures don't run on mysql workbench

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `french_generation`(in nfolks int)
BEGIN
    declare exit handler for 1452
    set @t = (nfolks - @x) * 0.5;
    set @r = 0;
    while @r < @t do
        insert into volunteer2languageSPEAK (member_num, `is 639_1`)
            values (@r+1, 'fr');
        insert into volunteer2languageREAD(member_num, `is 639_1`)
            values(@r+1, 'fr');
        set @r = @r + 1;
    end while;
END
```

The others are analogue to this.

Also check the insert by hand, and see if thes have an error.